# Cursor MySql regresa solo el primer resultado

Tags: mysql

estoy trabajando en un procedimiento en MySql para obtener un resumen de ventas de todas las sucursales en un rango de fechas dado utilizando cursores, pero al momento de ejecutarlo solo me regresa la información de la primera sucursal encontrada, no termina de iterar con el resto de sucursales.

La tabla de la cual obtengo las sucursales es esta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (num_suc_bsale)
FROM
    documentos_historico
WHERE
    num_suc_bsale IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY num_suc_bsale ASC

# num_suc_bsale
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
15
```

Y este es el procedimiento en el cual estoy trabajando:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `ResumenVentasGeneralSucursal`(fecha_inicio DATE, fecha_fin DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE fecha_inicio DATE DEFAULT fecha_inicio;
    DECLARE fecha_fin DATE DEFAULT fecha_fin;
    DECLARE total_bol INT default 0;
    DECLARE total_fact INT default 0;
    DECLARE total_nota_credito INT default 0;
    DECLARE total INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE prom DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
    
    DECLARE suc_fetch INT;
    
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    
    DECLARE cursor_1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT(num_suc_bsale) 
        FROM documentos_historico 
        WHERE num_suc_bsale IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY num_suc_bsale DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS resumen_ventas_gen;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE resumen_ventas_gen(id int not null auto_increment primary key,total_venta INT, total_boleta INT, total_factura INT, total_nc INT, promedio DOUBLE, mes DATE, sucursal INT);
    
    OPEN cursor_1;
    suc_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_1 INTO suc_fetch;     
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE suc_loop;
        END IF;
        
            WHILE fecha_inicio <= fecha_fin DO
                SET total_bol = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tipo_documento = 22 THEN total_venta ELSE 0 END) as total_boleta FROM documentos_historico WHERE num_suc_bsale = suc_fetch AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha_generacion_bsale, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%Y-%m'));
                SET total_fact = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tipo_documento = 5 THEN total_venta ELSE 0 END) as total_factura FROM documentos_historico WHERE num_suc_bsale = suc_fetch AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha_generacion_bsale, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%Y-%m'));
                SET total_nota_credito = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tipo_documento = 2 THEN total_venta ELSE 0 END) as total_credito FROM documentos_historico WHERE num_suc_bsale = suc_fetch AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha_generacion_bsale, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%Y-%m'));
                SET total = (SELECT SUM(total_venta) as total_venta FROM documentos_historico WHERE num_suc_bsale = suc_fetch AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha_generacion_bsale, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%Y-%m'));
                SET prom = (SELECT AVG(total_venta) as promedio FROM documentos_historico WHERE num_suc_bsale = suc_fetch AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha_generacion_bsale, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%Y-%m'));
                INSERT INTO resumen_ventas_gen(total_venta, total_boleta, total_factura, total_nc, promedio, mes, sucursal) VALUES(total, total_bol, total_fact, total_nota_credito, prom, fecha_inicio, suc_fetch);
                SET fecha_inicio = fecha_inicio + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
            END WHILE;
    
    END LOOP suc_loop;
    CLOSE cursor_1;
    
    SELECT 
    *
FROM
    resumen_ventas_gen;
END
```

No se si me está faltando algo al momento de invocar el cursor o en el while.
De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa del comportamiento obtenido se debe a la variable `fecha_inicio` la cual es incrementada en un (1) mes dentro de la instrucción `WHILE` en la primera iteración del cursor, pero al finalizar las iteraciones de la instrucción `WHILE` la variable `fecha_inicio` no es reasignada al valor original de entrada del procedimiento almacenado y siempre será mayor a la variable `fecha_fin`, por ello, en las iteraciones posteriores del cursor la condición `WHILE fecha_inicio <= fecha_fin DO` no se satisface, puede ver un ejemplo mínimo en el siguiente [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce01abd21d82617475a6cfa19275668f).

Igualmente, si así lo desea, puede aplicar algunas mejoras al procedimiento almacenado, por ejemplo:

- Puede obtener todas las variables (`total_bol`, `total_fact`, `total_nota_credito`, etc.) en una única sentencia `SELECT`, no sería necesario tener cinco (5) sentencias.
- Sin conocer en detalle su modelo y datos, posiblemente no sea necesario el cursor para obtener el resultado esperado, en una única consulta (posiblemente) pueda obtener lo que necesita.